# Ping being hijacked?

Tags: mac, network, security, dns, hacking

On my Mac terminal, I typed

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and I do a `dig`

```
dig www.facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.facebook.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29630
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.facebook.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.facebook.com.   1261    IN  CNAME   star.c10r.facebook.com.
star.c10r.facebook.com. 2   IN  A   31.13.70.1
```

Seems fine, but when I ping

```
PING www.facebook.com (193.107.16.114): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 193.107.16.114: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=584.127 ms
```

It use a Russian's IP address of `193.107.16.114`, and I don't have this entry in my `/etc/hosts/`

Any idea?

Update: Look like problem solved when I edit/save the `/etc/hosts/` file again, but definitely I don't have those strange IP `193.107.16.114` on my file, so I suspect due to any malware?

Comment: Certainly seems like something is doing something wrong. the Facebook.com ip address you should be getting in ping is: 173.252.120.6

Comment: http://193.107.16.114.ipaddress.com/

Comment: You should check your DNS server settings and report back here.

Comment: Which version of OS X? /etc/resolv.conf is deprecated in newer versions (starting with 10.8 I believe) and not used conventionally.